# location.href in IE & Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile, href, single-page-application

Having issues getting my one page web application to work in Internet Explorer and Edge. It works perfectly fine in other browsers.

The issue that I'm having is that I can't seem to get the navigation to work.

I've tried the following:

```
location.href = '#quickQuiz'
location.href = '/#quickQuiz'
window.location.href = '#quickQuiz'
window.location.href = '/#quickQuiz'
document.location.href = '/#quickQuiz'
document.location.href = '#quickQuiz'
function goHere(where) { window.location = where; return false; }
location.hash = '#quickQuiz'
location.hash = '/#quickQuiz'
```

All of them works perfectly fine on other browsers. What am I doing wrong?

http://www.snabbteori.se if you wanna see it for yourself.

**EDIT1: Additional code**

The item in my navigation menu looks like the following:

```
<li data-icon="info"><a id="teoriNav">Teori</a></li>
```

And then I check for a click event on it. I know that it's possible to just put `href="#teori` in there, but I am just using this one as an example, there are other links where I need to perform AJAX calls too, this one doesn't need it though just to verify there isn't something wrong with my AJAX calls causing it.

```
$(document).delegate('#teoriNav', 'click', function () {
    location.hash('#teori');');
});
```

I've also tried this but doesn't work:

```
$('#teoriNav').click( function() {
    location.hash('#teori');
});
```

**EDIT2: Updates**

I believe I've fixed all jQuery errors and some other issues. The only thing I'm getting in the Internet Explorer console is:

```
HTML1300: Navigation occured.
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching.
```

And then when I click on the button I get output which I wrote which confirms it registers my click on the button. But still it won't navigate.

**EDIT3: Ugly temporary fix**

It works after doing a page reload after navigating.

```
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

if(isEdge || isIE)
    location.reload();
```

But I hate the fact that the site has to reload, and if someone has a **real** fix for this I would really appreciate it...

Comment: What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: try using `location.hash`. Although not sure what issue really is. You didn't say what happens or doesn't happen or identify how your internal routing works. Provide all relevant code nd details

Comment: I've tried location.hash too without results. I want to display a different page.

Comment: not enough known for anyone to help and your link is useless as code in this question as soon as you resolve the problem and change it

Comment: What do you mean? There really isn't more relevant code to show. A function calls location.hash and it works on all browsers except IE & Edge, would you prefer a code dump of all my code, because I've really displayed all relevant code already.

Comment: I've added additional code as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Edge has an issue with links if your code is not propper. You should check your console for any errors, This is most likely.

We will need more information from your side to help you further.

Post your HTML and your Javascript (just relating to this area of problem)
and we can then better help you.

I sagest fixing your jQuery errors first and trying again.

Ok my Browser test have given me a variation of **30-60 error** relating to jQuery across Mac to Win. **These will need to be addressed**.

You also have a XSS issue that needs to be resolved. You have HTTPS from facebook but then HTTP on your website, These will need to match.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. What browser test did you run out of curiosity?

Comment: Could you run that test again? I think I resolved everything, at least what I could find.